# Solving Homogenous Linear Equation Initial Value Problem $Y''-4Y'-5Y=0 $at $Y(0)=2, Y'(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I've gone through this problem a few times and think I might be making a mistake somewhere along the way, because my answer isn't matching that of the back of the textbook.
I was given the equation:
$$Y'' - 4Y' - 5Y = 0 ; Y(0) = 2, Y'(0) = 1$$
I then wrote the auxiliary equation of:
$$r^2 - 4r - 5 = 0$$
From there I factored to solve for values of r
$$(r+1)(r-5) $$
so my values of r came to be: r = -1 and r = 5, so I wrote my two Y equations
$$Y_1 = e^{5t} \ \ Y'_1 = 5e^{5t}$$
$$Y_2 = e^{-t} \ \ Y'_2 = -e^{-t} $$
Then I set up a system of equations using the two initial values of Y(0) = 2 and Y'(0) = 1 to get
$$2 = C_1 + C_2$$
$$1 = 5C_1 - C_2$$
I Found C1 = 1/2 and C2 = 3/2, so I rewrote the general solution equation with values for C1 and C2
$$Y(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{5t} + \frac{3}{2}e^{-t}$$
However, the answer in the back of my textbook says:
$$2e^{5(t+1)} + e^{-(t+1)}$$
I'm really not seeing any clear place I messed up or how I would get to the answer in the back from my work.

Comment: Your question doesn't match your body.  If I go with what you said in your body, the initial conditions aren't satisfied by the book's answer. Your answer looks good to me.

Comment: Your answer is correct. 
The answer in the back of the book looks like the intial conditions were given at $t=-1$.

Comment: Your answer seems correct to me but the title dosent match the question in the body

Comment: @Isham Yes sorry about that, I was looking at the problem above the one I was working on when writing the title, but then started the body and wrote the correct problem.

Comment: No problem I did the calculation and everything is correct in your answer...

Comment: This is dumb question but you are looking at right section for correct answers by the  book? Sometimes we don't look at the headers super super hard.

Comment: @randomgirl Haha I would be lying if I said I hadn't made that mistake before, but I've triple checked now and all my answers to the questions around it are correct, it's just this one that doesn't match. Based off what others have confirmed, I'm guessing it's just an incorrect key, which has happened before in another section.

Comment: In the book's answer it is pretty obvious $y(0) \ne 2$  Which makes me think that something might be confused regarding the initial conditions.